# How to insert rows of few columns from one table into another and passing default values of few other columns?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert values of a few columns from one table say table1 into another table say table2. I'm doing this using SQlAlchemy. The code looks something like so:

`select_statement = select(some_columns_of_table1).where(and_(*some_clause))`
`table2_instance.insert().from_select(table2_columns, select_statement)`

This is working perfectly but now I have a use case that I need to update values of a certain column say column_x of table2. The data of column_x is always fixed i.e. `1`. If I run two separate queries for `table2_instance.insert().from_select(table2_columns, select_statement)` and updating `column_x` to `1`, it takes a lot of time because the table is quite huge. How can I customize the SQLAlchemy code to update `column_x`?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try raw SQL? `insert into table2 (...) select ..., 1 from table1 where ... `. Note the `1` in the select part. It's faster (no roundtrips) and safer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use raw query but i got the hint from your comment how to write that in SQLAlchemy. So i did this

`some_columns_of_table1.append(1)`

`table2_columns.append(column_x)`

`select_statement = select(some_columns_of_table1).where(and_(*some_clause))`

`table2_instance.insert().from_select(table2_columns, select_statement)`